# "Problems" scope in Pycharm

Tags: pycharm

I'm having trouble understanding the value or functionality of the "Problems" scope in PyCharm:
[image]

I'd like to make it show all files that the PyCharm `Code|Inspect` command finds errors with. Is this possible?

The [Documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/scope.html#predefined) doesn't reveal anything useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same as in [IntelliJ IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/scope.html): "Problems. This scope includes the files within the project content roots in which syntactic errors are found."